# One variant of the Knapsack Problem

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems

We have a normal knapsack problem but we can choose up to $t_i$ of the $i$-th object. How would you solve this problem with complexity less than $O(V(n + \sigma(t_i)))$ where $n$ is number of objects and $V$ is the total volume?

Comment: It seems the problem is NP-complete if all t_i are equal to 1.

Comment: What does $\sigma(t_i)$ represent?